# jquery delay execution of function

Tags: jquery, delayed-execution

I need a little guidance. I am trying to delay the execution of these two functions until after the page is fully loaded or timebomb them to happen after 5000 ms.

I am using the latest jquery 1.6

Thank you in advance for your help and code snippits :)

```
$("a.siteNavLink").each(function() {
   var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
   $(this).attr("href", _href + '?p=client');
});
$("a.footernav").each(function() {
   var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
   $(this).attr("href", _href + '?p=client');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Your code here
});
```

That will make your code run only when the document is fully loaded

[jQuery `ready()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: so along these lines
`$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.footernav").each(function() {
   var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
   $(this).attr("href", _href + '?p=client');
});
});`

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$(window).load(function(){ your code here }) // page has loaded including images
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){ your code here }) // dom has loaded
```